# document.body.appendChild() not working with <form>

Tags: javascript, html

I am running the code from w3schools to add button dynamically to the page. Here is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But this dynamic addition doesn't work when I have a `<form>` tag. What changes in the JavaScript I can make to accommodate dynamic button without having to remove the `<form>` tag?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't understand your statement "But this dynamic addition doesnt work when I have a tag".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesnt work when I have a tag". What yo uhave should work. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/tcgmf8r7/2/

Comment: What browser are you trying this in?

Comment: Sorry I meant doesnt work when I have <form> tag. The answer by @Laurianti below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('theForm').appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
```

```html
<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<form id="theForm">
</form>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for showing me the correct usage.

Comment: So if I have a div tag inside form, the implementation changes again? I tried to give a id for div tag and accessed that with getElementById. But that did not work

Comment: The solution doesnt work if I have the code as : function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('theForm').appendChild(btn);
}
</script><form id="theForm">
<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</form>

Comment: In the above code, in the <button> tag, I added type="button" and it worked! Thanks!